# VBA "kill file" not working on first run, but on all following runs

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I've run into a rather weird error on two VBA Scripts I wrote and can't quite put my finger on where the issue might lie exactly...

It's about two VBA Macros which handle the same functionality, one for Word and one for Excel.
What the macros do is parsing some information into a temporary .txt file which is created as such:

```
Dim Appl
Set Appl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /k im viewissue " & issue & " > " & "D:\temp" & issue & ".txt")
Appl.Terminate
```

Subsequently some information is extracted from the .txt file and written into the Excel/ Word files resprectively.

**EDIT:** As so:

```
Set FileNum = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("D:\temp" & issue & ".txt", 1)
   'Read some lines and write them into the Word/Excel files...
FileNum.Close
```

**end of Edit.**

After the macro is done with the file it deletes it:

```
Kill "D:\temp" & issue & ".txt"
```

Everything works without any problems: File is created, information extraction works, file is removed... EXCEPT on the first time you try to run it.

The first time you try to run it (on a freshly started up machine) you get a "Runtime Error 70: Access denied" connected to the line with the kill command.
If you just cancel the error message window and try again, it works fine.

I've checked the following:

- .txt file is created (even on first run)
- permissions are set correctly so as to be able to delete it manually without a problem
- same problem on both the Word and Excel macros after startup
- running the script on Word (with the error message) eliminates the problem on the first run of the Excel script and vice versa (even though the stranded .txt file has been removed after the missed attempt)

I really don't know what the problem might be... Don't quite see the difference between the first run and the subsequent ones.

Any kind of hint is much appreciated.
Cheers.

**EDIT:** On another note I've managed to rule out the possibility, that the FileSystemObject is the source of the problem, since I get the same issue when running the script without actually doing anything with the file.

Comment: Try Application.Doevents before.

Comment: How and where exactly would you call the function, Jochen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've accidentally come across the solution:

Turns out on the first run on a fresh machine the Integrity Client, which I'm calling with the "im"-command in the command line, is returning some information about the conncection.

This output seemed to have confused the script which led to it not closing the command window again thus keeping a file handle on the .txt file.
Resulting on the kill-command not being able to delete the file because of permission issues.

Thanks for all of your input, though!
Still much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Problems with code, that works 'while debugging or the second time' often emerge from cleanup or background processing. In many cases it helps to add a 'doevents' after calling the relevant parts. In your case you can try:

```
Dim Appl
Set Appl = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("cmd.exe /k im viewissue " & issue & " > " & "D:\temp" & issue & ".txt")
DoEvents
Appl.Terminate
Doevents
Kill "D:\temp" & issue & ".txt"
```

Hope the helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Jochen, but it's still not working. I still get the same issue on the first run...
See also my edit on the problem description above.

Answer (score 0):

Working on the assumption that MS Office's internal processes aren't done with the file you want to kill at the time you want to delete it, the easiest method should be to delay the deleting until some other time, for example, Before_Close. Another obvious time to kill the file would be before you use it again, but that would be counter-intuitive because when the name is reused the existing file would be over-written. I mean to point out that there isn't such a terrible rush to delete the file, and the MS engineers who designed their program not to let go of it promptly may have considered that fact.

Comment: A good suggestion, but the file is deleted at the very end of the script only...
I don't quitle like the idea of deleting the old file only at the next instance the script is run, since you have a file lying around the machine for quite some time, if the script isn't run regularly...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has the answer on this issue.  The file in question is probably open. 
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/291295/macro-code-to-check-whether-a-file-is-already-open
A variable pointing to a file can hold it hostage without you knowing it.  It will not allow you to delete it.  Set the variable to nothing and try again or better yet, try Microsoft's solution to check if the file is open before proceeding to delete it using kill or DeleteFile.

Comment: Link is dead...